# Which files generated from Ionic do I include in source control?

Tags: git, ionic-framework, version-control

I used this command to generate a new blank Ionic project: 
ionic start newapp blank --v1

I have the following files and folders generated:

[image]

I am not sure which ones I should be including or excluding from source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the layout that Ionic themselves follow on their [example apps](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app):

```
resources/
src/
www/
.editorconfig
.gitignore
config.xml
ionic.config.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
```

This removes the clutter of `node_modules` that can be rebuilt with `npm install` and the `platform` and `plugins` directories that can also be rebuilt.

If you want follow this layout, your `.gitignore` could look like this:

```
.sass-cache/
.tmp/
.versions/
coverage/
dist/
node_modules/
tmp/
temp/
hooks/
platforms/
plugins/
plugins/android.json
plugins/ios.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I also receive this message when doing an "npm install" in a fresh project folder with just Grayson Kent's structure above:

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
```

So the package-lock.json should also be committed to your source control.